# Blogger Facebook 'Like' Not in Feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, blogger

I've tried adding a Facebook Like button to my blogger site using the JavaScript SDK/XFBML and the iFrame methods.

The button will show up and it will work, but the notification never shows up in the Facebook News Feed -- only in the individual profile.

It doesn't seem to matter which method I use, so I've been fiddling with the iFrame. I tried this, but still, same problem -- notification doesn't show up in news feed:

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' expr:src='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;font=arial&amp;colorscheme=light&quot;' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:40px;'/>
```

Anyone out there have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Like button is intended to only show the person's friends that they have 'liked' your site. It is  an endorsement of reputation for your site. When a person who is a facebook friend of someone who 'liked' your site visits,then they will see (the name of their Facebook friend) 'and (x#) like 
 (name of your site)